# Semantic Segmentation with a dominant class

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I am training a semantic segmentation model consists of 3 classes(counting with the background).
The background is the dominant class, and the problem is that the model predicts every pixel as background.
I am currently using cross entropy loss function.

What are the solutions for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical strong imbalance for image segmentation; down below there are a couple of solutions to tackle this problem.

1. Use `Jaccard(IoU)` loss or `dice loss`; rather than optimizing for accuracy, you will optimise for the intersection over union, for example, and it has been demonstrated that they work much better than `cross_entropy` in case of imbalanced problems.
2. You may try to use class weights(sample weights in `Keras/TF`) in order to assign a greater importance for class 2 and 3 which are not background.
3. The `Focal Loss` has shown improvements in MLPs or other deep learning tasks, in which the dataset is strongly imbalanced. Focal loss can be combined with a loss from (1) and (3); it has the potential to improve your results.

You should expect to get the best performance improvement by employing (1) alone.